# Detection of pattern in Time Waveform Data

Tags: time-domain

I'm working on building a system which can detect such patterns by some methods excluding any statistical or frequency domain analysis techniques.

How to detect such repetitive pattern for any faulty system which is producing such data?

[image: strong text]**

Comment: can you give us more information about what makes this pattern special? Like, to me it looks like a sampled oscillation of some frequency. Cool, but if that was it, you probably would just have said "there's a tone that interferes with my measurement" or something; also, we can't know whether your signal of interest isn't that exact tone! So, take the guesswork out of this: give us more info on how this differs from the "healthy" signal! We can't help you without you doing much more describing desired and undesired signal. Your screenshot seems to be zoomed out too much, and not sufficient!

Comment: Do you know what the pattern is?

Comment: Hello, what I have here is a set of acceleration time waveform data originating from a malfunctioning machine. Upon examination, it appears that there is a recurring pattern within the data. We are currently investigating this using FFT analysis and other signal processing techniques. However, I am interested in automatically identifying any such patterns using the existing analysis methods.